# How to render mutliple 3d models with stlloader?

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I can't multiple models at the same time. When try render them, the display is white and blank. And console has no errors. I can render one model at a time. How do i render multiple at the same?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjSeS.png)

```
import * as THREE from './threejs/three.module.js';
import {STLLoader} from './threejs/STLLoader.js';
import {OrbitControls} from './threejs/OrbitControls.js';

let scene, camera, renderer, object;

function init(){
    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
        75,
        window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
        0.1,
        10000
    );
    camera.position.z = 10;

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    scene.add(object);

    let control = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

    let light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
    light.position.set(0,0,10);
    scene.add(light);

    let light2 = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
    light2.position.set(0,0,-10);
    scene.add(light2);

    animate();
    load1();
    load2();
}

function animate(){
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}


var ob1,ob2;

function load1(){
    loader = new STLLoader();
    loader.load('/左肾占位/NING_XUAN_QING_M_056Y_Violet_001.stl',(model)=>{
    ob1 = new THREE.Mesh(
        model,
        new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0x00ff00})
    );
    ob1.scale.set(0.2, 0.2, 0.2);
    ob1.position.set(0,-5,0);
    ob1.rotation.x = -Math.PI/2;
    init();
});

}


function load2(){
    let loader = new STLLoader();
    loader.load('/左肾占位/NINGXUANQINGM056Y_Turquoise_001.stl',(model)=>{
    ob2 = new THREE.Mesh(
        model,
        new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0x00ff00})
    );
    ob2.scale.set(0.2, 0.2, 0.2);
    ob2.position.set(0,0,0);
    ob2.rotation.x = -Math.PI/2;
    init();
});
}
```

model is Left renal mass, so it consists of multiple parts, every part has it's 3d model file i need to combine the all together to make it one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simplified version of what your code is doing:

```js
function init() {
  load1();
}

function load1() {
  init();
}
```

For starters, `init()` is never being executed. And if it were, you'd reach an infinite loop, like: `init > load > init > load > etc...`

Secondly, you're never adding the loaded objects to your `scene`, so there would be nothing to render anyway. Here's some pseudocode you should follow so everything gets executed in order, and only once:

```js
// Make scene and loader variables available
let scene, loader;

function init() {
    // Initialize scene and loader
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    loader = new STLLoader();

    // ...

    load1();
    animate();
}

function load1() {
    // Now we use the loader to import geometry
    loader.load("Violet_001.stl", (model)=>{

        // Once geometry is loaded, we build a mesh
        let ob1 = new THREE.Mesh(
            model,
            new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0x00ff00})
        );
        ob1.scale.set(0.2, 0.2, 0.2);

        // Now we add our Mesh to the scene so it can be rendered
        scene.add(ob1);
    });
}

function animate(){
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

// Finally, don't forget to start everything by calling init!
init();
```